# Reading StandardOutput problem

Tags: c#, javascript, stdout, redirectstandardoutput

I want to execute a javascript that returns a string like 'GEORGE SMITH'. I want to read that information but when y run this code I get: " The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application"

How can i capture this information?. I tried to call the javascript from a .bat but I cannot get the output from there. Can anyone help me?.

This is the code:

```
{
    Process proc = new Process();

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = "cardholder.js";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
    proc.Start();

    nombreApellido = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    proc.Close();
    proc.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript file is not an executable and you cannot run it.

You need to run wscript.exe and pass cardholder.js as a command line argument:

```
startInfo.FileName = "wscript.exe";
startInfo.Arguments= "cardholder.js";
```

Comment: it works this way, but which is the best way to read that information?

using StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); or should I use a StreamReader?.

Comment: Both can work and not much difference unless the script carries on running and you need to stop reading in which case second is better.

Answer (score 0):

cardholder.js is not an executable.  Your startInfo.FileName needs to be an executable.  You will need a javascript interpreter to 'run' the .js file.